# how can I set actions on UIImages when I am using them as buttons?

Tags: iphone, uibutton, uiimage

Hello
I am using images as buttons so how can I put event methods as they pressed, my coding is as below ...

```
UIImageView* view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"front_pag.png"]];
    view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    [self.view addSubview:view];


    new_button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
    UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"new.png"];
    [new_button setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [new_button setFrame:CGRectMake(85, 430, 0, 0)];
    [new_button addTarget:self action:@selector(newMethod) 
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:new_button];
```

what should I do, because in this case, I can't call newMethod, even I have this method in same class.

what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change your addTarget call to this:

```
[new_button addTarget:self action:@selector(newMethod:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Pay attention to semicolon after the `newMethod:` name

This is because the signature of your selector should be as following:

```
- (void) newMethod:(id) sender
```

This way it will be called.

Good luck

Comment: should I change it too, because your code is not working, my method is like this as below                                                                                                              -(void)newMethod {
 
 New *obNew = [[New alloc] init];
 [obNew setObjectforNew:myRunningObject];
 UINavigationController *cc=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:obNew];
 [self presentModalViewController:cc animated:YES];
 
}

Comment: you have to change the signature of your newMethod as I wrote in the answer because that what UIControl class expects to get as an action

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this out,

```
uiimage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"someImage.png"];
button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:img1 forState:UIControlStateNormal]
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0);
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: no it is not working, and can u can tell me that what is difference between my code and your code so that you think that it will work?

Comment: @veer, can you try checking the Frame , its width and height is zero.

Comment: @veer, welcome and please increase votes if its useful for you.

Comment: I have upvoted and sir see last two question for me, I also can't find there answer, I am new to programming iphone...